# datetimepicker is show reverse order for date and month

Tags: java, struts2, datetimepicker

I am use following code in my page and i return the result in same page but the display format will be changed as `MM/dd/yyyy` format.
How can i resolve this problem, please help me, thanks for advance.
Thank you.

```
<s:datetimepicker key="label.date.from" name="fromDate"
                        displayFormat="dd/MM/yyyy" toggleType="wipe" required="true" />
```

when i select the date it will display the correct format(dd/MM/yyyy), but the result is return the same page(after save in database. the db having correct format) it shows as MM/dd/yyyy(when month is >12 then it work fine otherwise it show as MM/dd/yyyy)

Comment: Where this datetimepicker is coming from?

Comment: That is the correct usage of the displayFormat property. When you select a date, is it displayed incorrectly?

Comment: @mmalmeida: Correct usage in which tag?

Comment: when i select the date it will display the correct format(dd/MM/yyyy), but the result is return the same page(after save in database. the db having correct format) it shows as MM/dd/yyyy(when month is >12 then it work fine otherwise it show as MM/dd/yyyy)

Comment: @AleksandrM - http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/datetimepicker.html